# How to grep string in perl

Tags: perl, grep

How to grep the string in perl.

Variable sessionWeb contains a web page html code. I want to grep "active Sessions" from this and want to print as below. For example the line in the web page will be

`"2 active Sessions, 0 passivated Sessions (more stats...)"`

Expected Output:

2 active Sessions.

I have tried the following code but it is not working ?

```
 $sessionStr="active Sessions";
     $sessionCount =~ grep( /$sessionStr/,$sessionWeb);
```

Comment: While we have traditionally welcomed questions about sysadmin-level scripting, this sort of question is really a better fit for [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should to the trick:

```
if ($sessionWeb =~ /(\d+ active Sessions)/) {
  print $1."\n";
}
```

Comment: It is printing the entire html page

Comment: The above code extracts only the requested part. There must be a bug in your code.